# Import data in certain Excel columns to Access by VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm using Access and need to import data from Excel.

The table has too many columns. What I do now is to find every cell I need, merge them, then insert into Access.

```vb
Set file = GetObject(path) 'get excel file
intArrNeedCols = Array(3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 26) 'the columns I need
For row = 2 To file.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count  'loop and collect values of each cell in the target column,the first row is title
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO orderlist VALUES("
    For Each col In intArrNeedCols
        strSQL = strSQL & "'" & file.sheets(1).cells(row, col) & "',"
    Next
    '…… 'other statements,like excute sql statement
Next
```

That is complex and hard to maintain. Is there an easier way?

Comment: You can link Excel sheets or you can use ADO.

Comment: Have a look at TransferSpeadsheet.

Comment: thank you,I will look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider directly querying from Excel inside MS Access append query which can also be used in DAO/ADO connections. I/O methods like `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` do not allow selecting specific columns in spreadsheet unless you create a special Excel tab or temp Access table.

In query below adjust named columns accordingly as well as file/sheet name reference. Escape any reserved words, spaces, and special characters with square brackets or backticks.

```sql
INSERT INTO OrderList
SELECT t.[Col1], t.[Col2], t.[Col3] ...
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Excel\File.xlsx].[SHEETNAME$] t;
```

Comment: I am curious, why an SQL Server answer to an MS Access question?

Comment: They have something incommon

Comment: Actually now I got a new question,I just did what you said,it works but found the empty cell will also be imported,how can I solve this problem.

Comment: And,my table has a column named "Shipping Date",I can't write it that way : t.Shipping Date Please

Comment: @Guoliangcai Why not look at an MS Access way of doing things such as I mentioned.

Comment: cuz I'm using excel,I want to make an excel application and I designed my GUI in excel..

Comment: @Guoliangcai - you can use square brackets or back ticks around field names with spaces/special chars and can use `WHERE` clause to filter out empty cells/rows like any other query. As for application, this query can be used in DAO/ADO connections in Excel VBA. Though I do recommend building app in Access a more robust application environment with built-in GUI tools but to each his own.

Comment: @Fionnuala - this is not a SQL Server answer as I was just borrowing its nomenclature of *distributed query* which no MS Access docs maintain such a term. But you bring up a good point, so I removed the line and link for clarity.

Comment: sure you got it